# Sed or awk to remove line with matched regex and following lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am filtering a log file and breaking it into sections based on category type. I got it to work on 1 category:

```
sed -e '/Associating reconciliation identity to/{N;N;d}' source.log  > destination.txt
```

The issue I am having comes when I search a different string and try to remove THAT line, and the 7 lines following. I am not 100% `sed` is the best tool, but I have not gotten `awk` to work at all. Based on the above example, I figured this should work:

```
sed -e '/Found multiple matches (instances) for class/{N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;d}' source.log  > destination.txt
```

Is there a better way?

---

Requested addition:

Source.log

```
<ERROR   > <TID: 140100592498432> /* Wed Aug 29 2018 05:18:20.7938 */ Found multiple matches (instances) for class <Software.Class> in look-up dataset <Category> 

<ERROR   > <TID: 140100592498432> /* Wed Aug 29 2018 05:18:20.7939 */ for qualification <'Name' != $\NULL$ AND 'Name' = $Name$> of group <Job-ID> with values 

<ERROR   > <TID: 140100592498432> /* Wed Aug 29 2018 05:18:20.7939 */ < Name = software.example >

<ERROR   > <TID: 140100592498432> /* Wed Aug 29 2018 05:18:20.7939 */ < RelLeadClassId = NULL >

<ERROR   > <TID: 140100592498432> /* Wed Aug 29 2018 05:18:20.7939 */ < RelLeadInstanceId = NULL >

<ERROR   > <TID: 140100592498432> /* Wed Aug 29 2018 05:18:20.7939 */ < RequestId = 00000000000|00000000000|000000000000 >

<ERROR   > <TID: 140100592498432> /* Wed Aug 29 2018 05:18:20.7939 */ < Secondary_UID = NULL >

<ERROR   > <TID: 140100592498432> /* Wed Aug 29 2018 05:18:20.7939 */ < TokenId = HashToken87hnUIKW22er4xbs78== >






<ERROR   > <TID: 140100593551104> /* Wed Aug 29 2018 05:18:20.7946 */ Found multiple matches (instances) for class <Software.Class> in look-up dataset <Category> 

<ERROR   > <TID: 140100593551104> /* Wed Aug 29 2018 05:18:20.7946 */ for qualification <'Name' != $\NULL$ AND 'Name' = $Name$> of group <Job-ID> with values 

<ERROR   > <TID: 140100593551104> /* Wed Aug 29 2018 05:18:20.7946 */ < Name = software.version >

<ERROR   > <TID: 140100593551104> /* Wed Aug 29 2018 05:18:20.7946 */ < RelLeadClassId = NULL >

<ERROR   > <TID: 140100593551104> /* Wed Aug 29 2018 05:18:20.7946 */ < RelLeadInstanceId = NULL >

<ERROR   > <TID: 140100593551104> /* Wed Aug 29 2018 05:18:20.7946 */ < RequestId = 000000000|000000000000|000000000000>

<ERROR   > <TID: 140100593551104> /* Wed Aug 29 2018 05:18:20.7946 */ < SERVICE_NOW_UID = NULL >

<ERROR   > <TID: 140100593551104> /* Wed Aug 29 2018 05:18:20.7946 */ < TokenId = HashTokenHHK72nsyUIOI92bYH== >
```

Comment: Please provide a short sample of `source.log` and `destination.txt` along with the expected result to make it easier to help.

Comment: expected result is to just remove this data from the source.log and the destination.txt would be all the data leftover after these lines are removed.
I'm filtering 130K lines of log. IDk if there's a max that sed can handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -e '/<search string here>/,+7d' source.log  > destination.txt
```

Comment: To qualify this a bit: I was trying to run the code in bash via Cygwin, and the "+" operator isn't supported in my current version of sed, but I can't upgrade my command list. Or I don't know how, 1 of the 2. And then apparently I didn't have the right permissions to run the above syntax directly on the server... SMH. So I did a bypass on permissions and now it's working.

Comment: Just re-run `setup.exe`, and it will update your Cygiwn software.  (Shut down all your Cygwin windows first.)

Comment: `sed --version` gives me
    `sed (GNU sed) 4.4, Packaged by Cygwin (4.4-1)`

Answer (score 1):

this will work for you:

```
grep -A7 -P 'regexhere' file| xargs -I {} sed -i.bak 's/{}//g' 1txt
```

Explanation:

*grep -A7 finds next 7 lines after the regex matches -P is for perl regex in grep*

*then we capture the output as lines from grep with xargs and use that entire line as replacement in sed command.*

*-i.bak option just creates a backup of the file that we are making changes to*

**P.S.: the above code will delete lines, you can always choose replacement as well with modifications.**